# Why does nohup not work as described with my connection to AWS through putty?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, ssh, python, putty

I am connecting to an AWS EC2 instance (ubuntu) from Windows 10 using Putty. When I try to do `nohup sleep 180 &` then `exit` and then connect again, the job is gone. I repeated with longer sleep and originally found this issue when trying to do it on some long running python code. I know about this post [...run in background after SSH logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975624/how-to-run-a-python-script-in-the-background-even-after-i-logout-ssh)  as everything I searched said same thing but it is not working for me. Is there something different about Windows 10 and Putty or something I am missing? I can try installing `screen` but I think nohup should just work?

Update on what I have tried so far. I referenced the suggested post on systemd. I used:

```
$ nohup sleep 180 &
$ grep Sig /proc/$!/status

SigQ:   0/60090
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000000000
SigIgn: 0000000000000001
SigCgt: 0000000000000000
```

Based on the post, this means that my problem is not "that the spawned process implements its own handler for `SIGHUP` "

So then I tried the following:

```
systemd-run --scope --user sleep 300
```

Then disconnected from wireless and tried to re-connect through Putty and the job was gone. Once the putty fails, the job stops.

Comment: Installing `screen` would also let you find out whether the problem is nohup-specific, or general to all similar tools.

Comment: I would bet that systemd is killing the job when you log out.  One of the many reasons there is so much hate against it... Anyway, check https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420594/why-process-killed-with-nohup